# Retrieving not only top one predictions from Multiclass Regression with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logistic-regression, predict

Once a multi-class regression model is built with Spark the output predictions will only show one result for each input.

With a simple example:
if a row **x** is predicted to belong to label **a** among 5 possible labels {a,b,c,d}
what would be the second label that classifies best row **x** ?

Comment: I am not sure it is a duplicate. It looks like you can calculate probabilites of the outputs coming from a NaiveBayes model, not a LogisticRegressionWithLFBGS which is the one I'm using @http://stackoverflow.com/users/3415409/eliasah

Comment: @zero323 please read above comment